# Where to find `android.annotation.Nullable`

Tags: java, android, nullable

If I open `android.content.SharedPreferences` class from SDK, I can see that it imports `android.annotation.Nullable` class, but I can't open that class, it's not on my classpath. And Android Studio does not recognize this annotation (so on my Kotlin code I'm not getting proper nullable types when using methods from SharedPreferences class). I have `android.support.annotation.Nullable`, `org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable`, `javax.annotation.Nullable`, but not `android.annotation.Nullable`.

I have `android.jar` from my SDK on classpath and there are two classes in `android.annotation` package: `SuppressLint` and `TargetApi`, but not `Nullable`.

I'm using Android Studio 3.3.1 and just created default project with Kotlin and 5.0 minimum target.

Comment: perhaps support Android annotation https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations?

Comment: It contains `android.support.annotation.Nullable`, I have it on classpath but technically it's a different class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blog](https://imnotyourson.com/which-nullness-annotation-you-should-use-on-android/) says: "`android.annotation.Nullable` is for internal usage only.  ...  Use `android.support.annotation.Nullable`."

Comment: Thanks. It's a pity, because I don't want to use it, but rather I just want Idea to recognize it. Probably I should go to Idea bugtracker.

Comment: I got here while trying to build Chromium for Android, and seems somehow files meant to be compiled into Android-OS got into my Android-App (my co-worker was trying to update to latest Chromium, seems I need to redo his work).