# How do you import the NonNull annotation correctly into android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, annotations

I want to use annotations for NonNull, Nullable and UnsopportedAppUsage in my Handler-file, but the 2nd, 3rd and 4th line gives me an error. How do I fix this?

```
package android.os;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.annotation.UnsupportedAppUsage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Printer;
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer is two-fold. For `@NonNull` and `@Nullable` do the following:

If you use androidx you need to add

```
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.2'
```

or if you use the legacy support library (your imports are for this version)

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
```

to your dependencies in the `build.gradle` file.
The version numbers might be different for you.

> **Note** that there is also the `android.annotation.Nullable` class, but it's internal API of Android-OS (causing [build errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54972404/8740349) if used).

For `@UnsupportedAppUsage`:
This annotation denotes that something that is internal to the Android SDK and shouldn't be used is actually in use. Using this annotation in your code doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Additionally the annotation is hidden in the SDK and cannot be used by you.

Answer (score 1):

In your app/build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
}
```

In your Java class:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
```

Then you use @NonNull in your field/variables like so:

```
@NonNull
public final JSONObject content;
```